# Is it technically possible to deploy J2EE (EAR) on same server as IBM Websphere Portal?

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, ear, portal

We are evaluating IBM Portal Server (8.5) as a new platform.  New applications would be built as JSR286 portlets; not a problem.  We have legacy J2EE applications running on WAS. Can we practically deploy these legacy EARs to the same server that is running Portal 8.5?  Happy to accept a white paper, IBM documentation link on this topic.  I am not finding it.

- Assume we have decent hardware to run both legacy EAR and Portal

  Not impressed by iFrame/Clipping portlets as we have too much JS in applications

  Not trying to communicate between these apps i.e. inter-portlet communication

  Licencing issues?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is technically possible as Websphere Portal is just a set of JEE applications running on WebSphere Application Server. You can install your own JEE applications directly to WAS along side of Portal.

However, I would contact your IBM sales representative as licensing may come into play if you plan to run custom applications on these WAS instances. From my experience, as long as your custom applications were supporting the portal, it was within the licensing agreement.